# How do I set a session variable and access it in javascript?

Tags: symfony

For as long as a user is logged in my javascript will need access to his/her client id. The client id is a custom id generated by a table in our database.

What is the Symfony2 way to store it in the session so that I can access it as long as he/she is logged in? How would I access it in Javascript?

Answer (score -1):

In your twig template

```
<script>
var clientId = "{{ client_id_from_database }}";
</script>
```

And then you can get it with js

```
alert(window.clientId || 'clientId is null')
```